# Can I get to the object of a property if I have a reference to the property only?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, reference

I have the reference to a property of an object in a variable,is it possible to access the object to which this property belongs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var obj = {
    p1: 1,
    p2: function(){
        return this;
    },
    p3: obj,
    p4: function() {
        return obj;
    }
}

// v1 is now integer, we cannot get actual `obj` from this `v1`
var v1 = obj.p1;

// `v2()` returns `window` object (or current context object), 
// so if `obj` is created only in global context (or current 
// context which you're calling `v2()`), you can get reference to `obj`
var v2 = obj.p2;

// as @Ignacio mentioned, you can use `v3` as reference to `obj`
var v3 = obj.p3;

// `v4()` also reference to `obj`
var v4 = obj.p4;
```

Answer (score 2):

Not unless the property value itself contains a reference to the object.

Comment: Or contains a reference to a function that can return the object.